# WebSocket message turns into weird characters at Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, websocket, corruption

We're trying to send a message via WebSocket in Firefox but when message exceeds some length it turns into weird characters like:

```
��
```

Is there anyway to set this buffer length or way out of this except sending the message as parts?

Comment: I do not think Firefox is the problem. Which WS server are you using?

Comment: Well, it works on Chrome.

Comment: And the character limit changes. But it is around 950.

Comment: The WS server is a windows service that we created. And there are no weird characters at the message normally as we tried it with only `a`s too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really weird but, we needed to rehandshake before sending our message.

That solved our problem.